# Why does SQL Server Management Studio 18 fail to connect to SQL Server 2014 SP3 without TLS 1.0 enabled on the Windows 2016 server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, tls1.2, tls1.0

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 using SQL Server Management Studio 2018 on a Win 2016 box from a my Windows 10 laptop.

My connection fails unless TLS 1.0 is enabled in the registry on the server.

The .NET framework on the Win10 laptop is 4.8.04084.

We have been advised to use TLS 1.2 instead of TLS 1.0.

TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are enabled in the registry on the Win2016 server for the client but no TLS 1.2 entries are present.

How do I force SQL Server Management Studio connection to used TLS 1.2 to connect to the SQL Server 2014 and what updates do I need on my laptop and on the server either to the registry or through version upgrades?

Comment: Which build of SQL Server? `select @@version` Which build of SSMS?

Comment: The Sql Server we are connection to is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4-GDR) (KB4583462) - 12.0.6433.1 (X64)   Oct 31 2020 02:54:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Comment: SSMS version on my laptop is 15.0.18410.0. Version 18.11.1

Comment: .Net Framework 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: I would recommend upgrading .NET as that version 4.5 does not support TLS1.2 unless specified.